# Using DTED file as raster elevation source at ArcGIS SDK for Qt?

Tags: elevation, c++, qt, dted, arcgis-runtime-sdk-qt

I am using ArcGIS SDK for Qt 100.7 for development and I was getting elevation from the code

`ArcGISTiledElevationSource* elevationSource = new ArcGISTiledElevationSource(QUrl("https://elevation3d.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/WorldElevation3D/Terrain3D/ImageServer"), this);`

However I want to gather elevation data when I am offline.

How can I pull elevation data to my GIS when I am offline for .dt2 file format?

Comment: I was going to suggest using [local server](https://developers.arcgis.com/qt/latest/cpp/guide/local-server.htm), but currently don't see any support for elevation services.  Still, maybe it's there and just poorly documented.

Comment: Actually I was thinking to solve problem by using local server as a plan b. I would serve my files from **127.0.0.1** and connect my server as a client and download dted file. But I am definitely not sure wheter it will work or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way to pull elevation data from the code below

````
QStringList filePath={"your/file/path"};

RasterElevationSource *elevationSource = new RasterElevationSource(filePath,this);```
````